# Xcode 8 Asset Catalog Vector Compile Error: actool failed with exit code 255

Tags: ios, xcode8

After upgrading to Xcode 8 a project no longer compiles and fails with error:

```
actool failed with exit code 255
```

I was able to narrow the issue down to pdf vector assets in the asset catalog. If I delete all of them, the project compiles successfully. I tried adding a single new vector asset, but compilation failed again with the error above. This is not happening in other projects with vector assets - only the 1 project. I have tried deleting derived data, cleaning, restarting, etc - nothing helped. Any advice to resolve would be appreciated please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to compile by changing the Deployment target to 8.0 from 6.0. Not sure why it is an issue in Xcode 8 as it worked with a deployment target of 6.0 in Xcode 7.